# Load non-existent flash file through service worker

Tags: xss, flash

Using Service Workers it is possible to load non-existent files with the fetch event handler, however this does not seem to work when loading flash files.

Is there any way in any browser to do this or a similar technique to load a "dynamically generated" flash file? Basically any way to load a flash file that doesn't exist on the server through some kind of client-side interaction.

Disclosure: related to ongoing events.

Comment: What result do you get when trying? Did you try custom responses as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Custom_responses_to_requests ?